# Why is there a single character replaced randomly in my string?

Tags: string, opengl, stdio

I'm writing a game in OpenGL4 using MinGW32 version 4.9.3. It contains this function:

```
void loadShaderFile(GLuint* shader, const char* filename, GLenum type){
    const char* path = "./res/shaders/"; // TODO: Proper path.
    char* fullPath;
    char* sourceCode;
    long fileLength;
    FILE* f;

    fullPath = malloc(strlen(filename) * sizeof(char) + sizeof(path) + 1);
    if(!fullPath){
        // TODO: Proper error handling.
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not allocate char* fullPath in void loadShaderFile()!");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    strcpy(fullPath, path);
    strcat(fullPath, filename);

    printf("%s\n", fullPath); // Prints correct path.
    printf("%s\n", fullPath);

    f = fopen(fullPath, "rb"); // Does not open.
    if(!f){
        // TODO: Proper error handling.
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not open %s in void loadShaderFile()!", fullPath); // Prints different string.
        free(fullPath);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    fileLength = ftell(f);
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);

    sourceCode = malloc(fileLength * sizeof(char) + 1);
    if(!sourceCode){
        // TODO: Proper error handling.
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not allocate char* sourceCode in void loadShaderFile()!");
        fclose(f);
        free(fullPath);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    fread(sourceCode, 1, fileLength, f);
    *(sourceCode + fileLength) = '\0';

    *(shader) = glCreateShader(type);
    glShaderSource(*(shader), 1, (char const * const *)&sourceCode, NULL); // Fucking pointers.
    glCompileShader(*(shader));

    fclose(f);
    free(sourceCode);
    free(fullPath);
}
```

Here is the output when called as `loadShaderFile(&vs, "defaultVertexShader.glsl", GL_VERTEX_SHADER)`:

```
./res/shaders/defaultVertexShader.glsl
./res/shaders/defaultVertexShader.glsl
Error: Could not open ./res/shaders/defaultVertexShader.g$sl in void loadShaderFile()!
```

As you can see, fullPath contains the correct path to defaultVertexShader.glsl, but as soon as fopen is called, it replaces the first l in the file extension to a random ASCII character, a different one every time it's run. I think it might be a bug in stdio.

Comment: `sizeof(path)` is not the size of your string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
const char* path = ...
fullPath = malloc(strlen(filename) * sizeof(char) + sizeof(path) + 1);
```

`path` is not an array, but a pointer, so `sizeof(path)` will yield `sizeof(const char *)`.

Comment: I changed `const char* path` to `const char path[]`. Worked like a charm.